# Bypass AWS rate limits on local dockerized dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, rate-limiting

I have a test suite that connects to the [dockerized dynamodb](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/).

```
// Start container with:
// docker run --name dynamodb -p 9000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local

const mockConfig = {
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:9000',
    accessKeyId: 'mockAccessKeyId',
    secretAccessKey: 'mockSecretAccessKey',
    region: 'mockRegion',
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
}
const documentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient(mockConfig)
...
test('Foo query', async () => {
    const x = await documentClient.query({...}).promise()
    expect(x).toEqual({...})
})
```

Which is working fine.  The problem is when I run the tests too quickly in succession, I get this error:

```
{
    "error": "Too Many Requests",
    "message": "You have died of dysentery. Oregon Trail",
    "status": 429,
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this rate limiting locally? There doesn't appear to be a rate limit setting for the docker container. I imagine this will become more of an issue when I have more tests running asynchronously.